# Changing indentation in exam class

Tags: indentation, exam

I'm currently writing an exam and require specific indentation on the left to match the following:

[image]

I have been using exam class and have now sorted out the right margin and exam marks but my left indentation is not right. As you can see below, information after the question has been indented, as has  the enumerate. Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm a bit of a novice!

[image]

Comment: Actually, the hardest part to change is left justifying the numbers instead of right justifying them in boxes.  It is built into \item itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you want the part and subpart indentation to be equal.  I arbitrarily chose `\leftmargini`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only, to show first margin
\marksnotpoints

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Question \thequestion.}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\leftmargin=0pt%
  \labelwidth=-\labelsep}
  
\renewcommand\partlabel{\hbox to \labelwidth{\alph{partno}.\hfil}}
\renewcommand{\partshook}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\leftmargini}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{\dimexpr \leftmargin-\labelsep}}
  
\renewcommand\subpartlabel{\hbox to \labelwidth{\thesubpart.\hfil}}
\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\leftmargini}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{\dimexpr \leftmargin-\labelsep}}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[4]\hfill

This is the first question.
\begin{parts}
\part
This is a part.
\part
\begin{subparts}
\subpart
This is a subpart.
\subpart
This is a periscope.
\subpart
This is a pair of diving planes.
\end{subparts}
\part
It's sad to be apart.
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way i can use \begin{itemize}
    \item...... (1 mark)
  \item ...... (1 mark)
  \item ........ (1 mark)
\end{itemize} in exam document class

Comment: @ElijahOjiambo - Not sure what you want to do with "(1 mark)".  If you intend to use exam class points, you should use `questions` etc. environments.  They are based on `itemize`, but with lots of additions.  Note that `\question` calls `\item` internally.

Comment: 1 mark is points dropped on the right margin